# Access Twitter or Facebook API from Java ME app?

Tags: java, facebook, mobile, twitter

I'm developing a Java ME app and I want to give it social features. Is it possible to connect to Facebook or Twitter directly from the app, without an intermediate server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These API's are just HTTP when it comes down to bits-on-the-wire. Java ME supports HTTP with the classes in the javax.microedition.io.* package.

http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html

http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html

It's been a while but ISTR having to use GET and POST for everything when using these, no RESTful PUT and DELETE.

Comment: as Licky said
Facebook API is basically a REST API
the most crucial thing within the whole classes ist the correct calculation of the fb_sig (the checksum of all send POST params combined with APP Secret)

Answer (score 2):

[Java Client Libraries for the Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries#Javanbsp)

[Facebook access for Java](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)

Those should get you started.

You don't need to use any type of middleware or anything to access services that expose an API, but you will need a client library that either you or somebody else has built (like the ones linked to above).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm developing for Java ME and these libaries don't seem to be compatible. Any other ideas?